# Sign in with a pre-built account without manually login - Android Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, android-activity, google-drive-api

I'm doing a research project and I need to install an app on 30 devices, all of them without a google account. What I need to do is save the results of the app in my google drive folder (I have its id). At the moment this is my sign in process, which asks for a google account:

```
private void requestSignIn() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting sign-in");
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                    .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
            if (resultCode == this.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
                handleSignInResult(resultData);
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
}

private void handleSignInResult(Intent result) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
            .addOnSuccessListener(googleAccount -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "Signed in as " + googleAccount.getEmail());
                // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
                GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                        GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
                credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());
                Drive googleDriveService =
                        new Drive.Builder(
                                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                new GsonFactory(),
                                credential)
                                .setApplicationName("Drive API Migration")
                                .build();

                mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(exception -> Log.e(TAG, "Unable to sign in.", exception));
}
```

Since I know my credentials and the IDs of the directory where I need to work, is there a way to modify the code and incorporate my account in the sign in process so I don't need to configure a google account on the devices?

Comment: Google drive is a google product to access a google account you need to sign-in with google.  Your code asks the user to sign-in it appears to be doing what it was intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

1. Make an HTTP backend to send the data to. What comes to mind is an Apps Script web app (post event with content service), or a Google Cloud function with an HTTP trigger.
2. Use a service account with the permissions very narrow (hard to do and anyone with the application would be able to use that account).

### References

- [Overview of Google Apps Script (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Web Apps (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Cloud function (Google Cloud)](https://cloud.google.com/functions)
- [Service accounts (Google IAM documentation)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)